# How to properly display RTL text followed by number in svg text element for Chrome/Firefox/IE/Edge?

Tags: css, svg

The following code displays RTL text as intended on Chrome/Firefox, but not IE/Edge. I want it to start from x coordinate and increase to left

```
<text x="300" y="10" style="direction: rtl;">מאי - יוני 2016</text>
```

- If I apply **text-anchor: end** - the text overlaps with number in IE / Edge, but in Chrome / Firefox is displayed from x coordinate to the right

https://jsfiddle.net/blteblte/ru7xzydv/2/

Is there any unified approach to satisfy at least the most popular browsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `dir` attribute and add "rtl" as value in text element inside SVG to show RTL text in IE/Edge.

Check link for updated code:
https://jsfiddle.net/ru7xzydv/3/